# Cannot read property '_header' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, image, express

The offending code is the `app.use(express.static("web"))` line.

```js
var express = require('express')();
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

//app.get('/', function(res, req) {
// res.sendFile(__dirname + '/www/index.html');
//})

app.use(express.static("web"));
```

which returns the following error in console:

```html
/Users/matthewwalker/CVLGBT/CVLGBT/www/node_modules/finalhandler/index.js:92
    if (!err && res._header) {
                    ^

TypeError: Cannot read property '_header' of undefined
    at /Users/matthewwalker/CVLGBT/CVLGBT/www/node_modules/finalhandler/index.js:92:21
    at Function.handle (/Users/matthewwalker/CVLGBT/CVLGBT/www/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:170:5)
    at app (/Users/matthewwalker/CVLGBT/CVLGBT/www/node_modules/express/lib/express.js:38:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/matthewwalker/CVLGBT/CVLGBT/www/index.js:2:11)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
```

Other times when I change up the code slightly I get `express is not defined`. File structure: index.js and node modules under root, while all html/css/js/imgs are under /web. I'm not sure why this header flag is being thrown. When I use the `app.get` line, it only sends the html file but no images or js. I need to be able to serve the whole directory of /web.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're constructing an `app` instance on the first line, and then calling it on line 2:

```
var express = require('express')();
var app = express();
```

You should do this instead:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
```

Or this:

```
var app = require('express')();
```

You can find more information about the express api [here](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html).

Comment: Marry me. You have saved me a lot of trouble! Thank you sir!